# For loop improved with ">>>" operator?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, mootools

I'm updating mootools from 1.3.2 to 1.4.1.
I saw a strange change. From this

```
for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++){....
```

to this

```
for (var i = 0, l = this.length >>> 0; i < l; i++){
```

how the ">>>" operator, used in that way, can improve performance? What do you think about it?

Comment: WUT?! But, (5 >>> 0 == 5)... xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `>>>` bitwise operator is bounded between and including 0 and `2^32-1` (4,294,967,295). By using using `>>>`, the framework ensures that the loop does not execute near-infitite times.

PS. *The context of the code:*

```
Array.implement({every: function(fn, bind){
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length >>> 0; i < l; i++){
        if ((i in this) && !fn.call(bind, this[i], i, this)) return false;
    }
```

Since `i` is initialised at zero, and incremented by an integer 1, and the `length` property is always an integer, there are no negative side-effects. Another application of the `>>>` method is rounding, to convert a decimal number to an integer.

Comment: @Antonio Please remember to accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it if it solved your question  :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the reason is some kind of conversion to make sure that the value is always numeric (as opposed to eg. the string '2').

Comment: @Cipi not here. `('5' >>> 0) === 5` gives `true`

Comment: loose typing means that won't matter. '.length' will only be non-numeric on an array-like item (object.length = "foo");

Answer (score 1):

Keeto from mootools team shed some light as to 'why' they do this, the answer is, generics and array-likes.

All array methods are supposed to also work as Array.every / Array.prototype.every calls. Which means, you can pass on an object with .length: -1 or similar.

This ensures the length will not be invalid for the loop to fail, I suppose.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call({0:1, length: -1});
```

Comment: *"Keeto from ... and array-likes"* `[citation needed]`. That aside, `-1 >>> 0` equals `4,294,967,295`, which is not equal to the behaviour of a length of -1. The `(i in this)` part of the expression results in the desired effect, but looping 4.3E9 times to achieve the effect of `-1` is extremely inefficient.

Comment: ok, bad example, this, neg values is one thing it won't work on. strings, null, even functions etc --> most will return 0

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this "bitshift by zero" technique used as a quick'n'dirty truncate method.

e.g.:

```
42.8989 >>> 0 == 42
```

however, this misappropriation of bitshifting might go seriously wrong if you feed in a negative number:

```
(-42.8989) >>> 0 == 4294967254
```